# Reverse Engineering C# code using StarUML

Tags: c#, reverse-engineering

I am trying to convert my C# code to design (Reverese Engineering) using StarUML. I got the error while performing the Reverse engineering

> "Error occurred in the process of reverse engineering. message : Catastrophic failure".

After the error, the application crashed.

Could anyone suggest a solution for this please?

Answer (score 3):

One of the problems with staruml is that apparently it does not support generics and when a file has the "<", a parser error occurs

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with StarUML in particular, although there are a couple of ways that it could be going about the process of documenting your assemblies. The most likely method is .Net reflection.

Lots of applications struggle with the more recent C# optimisations.

The best application for reflecting code back out is [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector), and there are plug-ins that will generate UML for you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a parser error of StarUML. You may try other UML software such as ModelMaker for C#.